# Law of total probability

Tags: descriptive-statistics

A company does drug test when doing interviews to ensure it doesn't get any addicts.

If a person uses drugs, the test will show that they do so with 95% probability. If a person doesn't use drugs then the test will show so with 90% probability. If we presume that 4% of the interviewed people use drugs.

a) Count the probability of the test showing "uses drugs"

The problem is, I got right answer, but I have some error in my method.
So, basically `A = uses drugs`, `B = test shows uses drugs`

If we use law of total probability, we want $P(A)$, but that disturbs my formula as: $P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B')P(B')$ where $P(A|B)$ is using drugs if the test shows it and $P(B)$ is uses drugs. But how can both $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ be uses drugs? And if we don't assume so, we cannot get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I inverted A and B in my computation but the concept is the same. 
I found a little confusion in your formulation. So, if you model P(B) as probability of the person doing actually drugs and P(A) the probability og having a positive test, the problem gives you P(A|B): given that a person uses/doesn't use drugs, what is the probability that the test is positive. 
You want, basically, P(A=positive). So, you compute P(A=true) = P(A=true|B=uses drugs)*P(B=uses drugs) + P(A=true|B=not using drugs)*P(B=not using drugs). 
You say that you want to compute the probability of the test being positive but I see that tou compute P(A), that as you said is the probability that the person actually uses drugs.